# iTerm 2 on Mac OS X - How to get rid of all characters before the $ on each line?

Tags: terminal, terminal.app, iterm, iterm2

I installed iTerm 2 but my shell windows show:

```
"computer name":"current directory" "user" $
```

This is far too long. I'd like to just see:

```
"current directory" $
```

Is there an option for this? I couldn't find it in the preferences.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's behavior of your *shell*, not your *terminal*. If you're using bash, edit `~/.bash_profile` and add the following line:

```
export PS1='\w \$ '
```

This will display the current working directory, or `~` in case of `$HOME`, and either `$` or `#`, depending on whether you're `root`. Examples:

```
/Applications $
~/Documents $
/Users/danielbeck/Documents #
```

Search `man bash` for `PS1` to find out about the possible placeholders. You can execute shell scripts as part of your prompt, e.g.:

```
export PS1='$( pwd ) \$ '
```

This will behave similar to the one above, but always print the full path.